# Title bar color

Tags: wpf

How come that on one computer the WPF tile bar is blue and on another one white?

[image]

On another PC it is white, it has to do with computer version?

I don't do anything special in code.

[image]

Comment: If you do not do anything special in your code it reverts to your systems default window behaviour - if you use different OS (Windows 8 vs 10) or have different Designs chosen or use a hiugh contrast setting for one you might get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in Windows 10 under `Settings > Personalization > Colors` called *Title bars and window borders*. In the second image it must be off. By the way it's turned off by default.

[image]